# unable to download webgl content ever after specifying preserveDrawingBuffer = true in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webgl, html2canvas, heremaps

I am getting "unable to clone WebGL context as it has preserveDrawingBuffer=false" error even after specifying  preserveDrawingBuffer = true in my code. I was trying to download a div with HERE MAPS using html2canvas library in vue. Below is the function I wrote for downloading the div content as image.

```
downloadImage() {
  const scale = 4 // Specify the quality in megapixels
  const myDiv = this.$refs.hereMap
  const divCan = document.querySelector('#map canvas')
  const gl = divCan.getContext('webgl')
  gl.preserveDrawingBuffer = true
  const clone = divCan.cloneNode(true)
  console.log(divCan)
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = myDiv.offsetWidth * scale
  canvas.height = myDiv.offsetHeight * scale

  // Create a WebGL context with preserveDrawingBuffer set to true
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  ctx.scale(scale, scale)
  html2canvas(myDiv, { canvas: canvas, useCORS: true, logging: true, letterRendering: 1, allowTaint: true, imageTimeout: 0 })
    .then(function(canvas) {
      canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, 'my-div-image.png') // Download the image
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: I got the answer need to specify this before initializing the web gl content, basically before mounting the component.
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(origFn) {
  return function(type, attribs) {
    attribs = attribs || {};
    attribs.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
    return origFn.call(this, type, attribs);
  };
}(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext);

Comment: It's been 6 months, but this answer saved my script. For newbies like me, and correct me if I'm wrong, remember to run this code before rendering the canvas. You should mark this code as the 'best answer'.